# Terminal closes after few milliseconds

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nautilus

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04, I am trying to add `Open in terminal` option, so that I can open terminal within any directory directly.

I installed nautilus-open-terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

and then logged off and logged in again.

After right clicking within any folder I was getting an option of `Open in Terminal`, but when I click it, terminal opens for few millisecond and closes again. The terminal screen just flashes in for few ms. 
While when I open terminal normally by `Ctrl+Shift+T`, terminal is working good.
Am I missing anything? Any help will be appreciated.TIA.

Comment: Can you check in your .bash_rc file in your home directory, or in scripts in /etc/profile.d to see if there are any commands that crash when started, or if there is an exit command in the wrong place?

Comment: How can I know whether any command crashed or any exit command placed at wrong place?

Comment: You would have to look through the .bash_rc file in your home directory, all the scripts in /etc/profile.d, and all scripts included in starting up a new terminal session. Just scan it and see if there is an exit placed somewhere, or see if there is a command run in those scripts that crashes when it is run.

Comment: I don't see anything as such in my .bash_rc .

Comment: You will have to search through all the files that are gone through when starting up and creating a new terminal session to see if there is anything that crashes when it starts, causing the terminal itself to crash. You could install guake to have a drop down terminal and see if that is a work around. You could start gnome-terminal from guake and see if it prints an error you can troubleshoot. Here is a link to info about how terminal sessions are started that you should read: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html